# htaccess redirect image folder from domain to directory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

In the html I have such urls for images :

```
<img src="/images/folder1/folder2/images.jpg" />
```

the index.html file is located in the domain folder:

```
http://example.com/test
```

the images are not displayed because in developer tools the path points to :

```
http://example.com/images/folder1/folder2/images.jpg
```

instead:

```
http://example.com/test/images/folder1/folder2/images.jpg
```

Is it possible to redirect an appropriate htaccess?

Funny

This rule works for a = href but doesn't work for img = src .. why?

I have this html:

```
<a href="/images/folder1/folder2/images.jpg">
<img src = "/images/folder1/folder3/images.jpg">
</a>
```

for url it works fine - moves to /test/images ... but for img = src not

My main question is this:

Why does the rule work if we put it in the root of example.com, and it stops working if we move all files to example.com/test?

Comment: Why would you want to “fix” this by redirecting, instead of using the _proper_ URLs in the HTML to begin with?

Comment: because the site is supposed to work in three different environments:
1.local when creating the page by me http://sitelocal.com
2. client preview http://web.example.com/client_folder
3. finally on the target domain http://clientdomain.com

I use TinyMCE to edit content where I have set the image paths to / images /. In point 1 and 3 it works fine in point 2 no

In any case, I would have to modify the paths in the database to make it good for a given domain

Comment: @anubhava yes i tried.. `RewriteRule ^/images/(.*) http://example.com/test/images/$1` but not work

Answer (score 0):

You may use this redirect rule for images:

```
RewriteRule ^images/.*$ /test/$0 [L,NC,R=301]
```